# Problems with M2E Pro plugin correctly detecting product/ASIN from barcode

Tags: extensions

We use the M2E Pro plugin for selling on Ebay and are now in the process of setting up with Amazon.

The problem is in finding the ASIN. The plugin correctly matches some products from the barcode, for others it gets the brand/product right but some other detail like colour wrong and finally for others it's completely off the mark (though the product is sold by others on Amazon).

Is there any way to make the detection more accurate? The barcodes are going in correctly and the item titles pretty much match Amazon's naming convention - so I'm not sure what the issue is. Is there a problem with settings - or the installation of the plugin itself?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the product mapping can be pretty loose when it comes to results and you may end up with some false positives. Rather than trying to automatically assign the ASIN you might be better off manually assign it per product. Obviously this can be a long process.
It might be worth creating an attribute on your products where you can input the ASIN code and then you can map that to Amazon's ASIN from within the M2e listing configuration so they should correctly match.

Please note that Amazon is still in beta and it can be rather flakey - I'm sure this will improve over time.